# Как с помощью цикла создавать новый луч и постоянно менять его направление?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Привет. Есть такой код -

```
Vector3 rayDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-Spread, Spread), Random.Range(-Spread, Spread), 0);
    Ray ray = new Ray(BulletSpawn.position, BulletSpawn.forward + rayDirection);
    RaycastHit raycastHit;
    RaycastHit checkHit;
    Distance = MaxDistance;
    for(float distance = MaxDistance; distance > 0; distance -= 20)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(BulletSpawn.transform.position, BulletSpawn.forward + rayDirection, out raycastHit, Distance))
        {
            PrintDecal(raycastHit);
            Distance -= 20;

            rayDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-WoodSpread, WoodSpread), Random.Range(-WoodSpread, WoodSpread), 0); // Здесь пытаюсь сделать преломление луча

            Ray checkRay = new Ray(raycastHit.point + ray.direction * 1.2F, -BulletSpawn.forward);
            if (Physics.Raycast(checkRay, out checkHit, 3))
            {
                PrintDecal(checkHit);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы было как на изображении - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То-есть, при попадании создавался следующий луч(со случайным направлением) с точки checkHit(точка вылета условной пули). Можно это реализовать, не создавая пять методов для каждого луча, а чтобы все в одном методе было. Такое возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все. Разобрался. RaycastAll не подходит. Нужно каждый раз создавать prefab который будет пускать новый луч, и передавать туда данные о направлении.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, но немного сложнее, и тем кто будет с вашим кодом работать позднее разбираться тоже